# Metrics for classifiers with unclassified objects

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to solve binary classification problem with specific classifier. It can return unclassified objects. What is the best metric in this case? For example I can use f1 score, but it cannot take into consideration the number of unclassified objects. Maybe this problem already has traditional approach.

Comment: What is an unclassifiied object? Is it basically that the classifier can object to classify certain objects if it is not confident enugh about the classification?

Comment: Yes it is. I didn't know the right definition for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are refering to abstaining classifiers.

*"In many application areas of machine learning it is
not sensible to predict the class for each and every
instance, no matter how uncertain the prediction is.
Instead, classifiers should have the opportunity to abstain
from risky predictions under certain conditions"*
http://users.dsic.upv.es/~flip/ROCML2006/Papers/friedelROCML06.pdf

This paper also gives a very elaborate visualization technique. In general searching for evaluation+abstaining+classifier will provide you quite a few metrics.

If you want something simpler you can easily develop something from scractch if you can define a cost function. A cost function assigns a value to `TP` `FP`,... Based on this you can calculate the *value of a classifier* by calculating the weighted sum over the confusion matrix.